# How to handle data received in a query Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following:

```
 $get = array(trim($this->db->get_where('base', array('key' => 'courses'))->row('value'), '"[]'));
 //$get_2 = array('1', '2', '3');
 $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
 $this->db->limit('8');
 $this->db->where('status', 'active');
 $this->db->where_in('id', $get);
 return $this->db->get('course')->result_array();
```

In the database it looks like this:

[image]

The `$get` variable makes the query in this table.

The problem is that it doesn't work, if I use `$get_2` it works normally, what can it be?

Strange because the values are exactly the same as `$get` and `$get_2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because, ***IF*** the output of *$get* is *'1','2','3'*, it failed to be put in an array like that. Try ***explode();***:

```
 $get =  str_replace("'", "", trim($this->db->get_where('base', array('key' => 'courses'))->row('value'), '"[]'));
 $get_data = explode(',',$get);
 //$get_2 = array('1', '2', '3');
 $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
 $this->db->limit('8');
 $this->db->where('status', 'active');
 $this->db->where_in('id', $get_data);
 return $this->db->get('course')->result_array();
```

Now, it becomes an array in *$get_data*, which you can access via *$get_data[array_index];*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221000/discussion-on-answer-by-bonifacius-sarumpaet-how-to-handle-data-received-in-a-qu).